# Google Analytics and Drupal's base site

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, drupal-6

I have one Drupal 6 install running several sites or themes. For example:
    www.example.com/site1
    www.example.com/site2
    www.example.com/site3

There was not a site at www.example.com except for a landing page acting as a place holder.

Google Analytics was setup with www.example.com as the Property and each site as a separate View. Reporting was fine for sites 1, 2, 3 and we did not care about the base site because nothing was there.

Now, we just launched the base site, www.example.com, but Google Analytic includes stats for sites 1, 2, 3 in its reporting.

In the view for www.example.com we set up custom filters to exclude the other sites. It's a custom filter to exclude the Request URI with the pattern of site1. A second filter for site2 and a third for site3. However the filters are not working.

Does anyone have a recommendation for setting up Google Analytics so I can get reporting on just the base site?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the filter configuration? Or paste the code into the question?

Comment: It's possible that you need to wait a few hours until the reports are updated.

Comment: @Blexy I don't have a high enough reputation to post an image. So I create a page on our site with them. I hope that's OK. [Link] (http://www.alliancenet.org/google-analytics-problem)

Yes, Google says 24 hours. It was about a week ago that we configured the filters.

Comment: Do you have different GA embed code for main site?

Comment: @MilanG I'm embarrassed now, I asked your question to my developer who responded "Nope, it’s the same code. Wait, there isn’t a tracking code at all on alliancenet.org?" So it looks like he forgot to add the GA embed code. I'll report back if that fixed it or not.

Comment: :) From whay I know, GA is tracking pages, not domains...correct me if I'm wrong.